# Preventing JavaScript 'functions' running on client

Tags: javascript, security, client

Is there some way to prevent certain 'functions' in JavaScript from running on the client. I have concerns that something like Mimikatz that could be run from memory and enable a hacker to compromise a host. Ideally this would detect definable code that is not allowed to run and prevent execution.

Comment: You cannot control an HTTP client at all. (From your server, I mean.)

Comment: Many browsers have an option to disable JavaScript entirely.   Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi Peter...i don't want to disable javascript as that would impact the user web experience, whitelisting would have some benefit but is by no means failsafe so what I'd like to do is have a plugin perhaps analyze the javascript to determine if there is, as defined in a policy, commands that should be allowed to run and then. based on a policy trigger and action such as not allowing the code to run.

Comment: sorry - should NOT be allowed to run :)

Comment: Are you talking about an [XSS attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) or a user running script from the developer console? If the latter then all the user is doing is running stuff in their browser, not on your server, and all they can do is "attack" themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am looking from the user's perspective. If they launch code, zeus, mimikatz etc..., knowingly or not, that could compromise the host and initiate a broader breach

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with what you're describing. The first is that it's very easy to obfuscate JavaScript. For example, let's say you didn't want the eval function to be executed. It's easy enough to design a regular expression that would remove direct calls to eval. Except what if it's not named eval anymore?

```
var e = eval;
e('evil');`
```

You could detect that too, but you end up going down a rabbit hole trying to anticipate obfuscation techniques. If you really want to do this, I suggest starting with a browser plugin like Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey. It's going to be a lot of work and you'll get a lot of false positives.

Another issue is deciding what to block. Depending on implementation, there are only a dozen or so [global functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) in JavaScript, plus another few dozen global objects. Which will be blocked? None of them are inherently dangerous unless there's a vulnerability in the JavaScript engine or browser. If you're aware a vulnerability, patching is going to be far safer and easier than filtering JavaScript.

The most common way that JavaScript is used in attacks is through cross-site scripting (XSS). The two main approaches are using a malicious script to steal data from the domain, or reformatting the page to prompt the user for sensitive data (usually credentials or payment card numbers). Both techniques use the same JavaScript functions that legitimate pages do, so it's effectively impossible to prevent by analyzing the JavaScript. It is possible to block simple XSS attacks by looking for JavaScript in a request parameter, but browsers already do that.

Your specific example of Mimikatz isn't JavaScript-specific. Mimikatz is a generic tool for post-exploitation. In other words, the attacker must first find a way into your system, then uses Mimikatz to make it easier to stay in and perform mischief. Again, without an initial vulnerability in the JavaScript engine or browser, an attacker won't be able to run something like Mimikatz using JS.

If you're still worried, look at a plugin like NoScript. It supports policies defining which domains can run JavaScript. It's not as granular as you'd like, but it's easy to setup.

Comment: ahhh...great answer and I appreciate you sharing your expertise. So if a restricted normal privileged user executed 'Mimikatz.js', for example, it  would only potentially provide results commensurate with the privilege level of the user. Presumably loading a driver and injecting code could also not be instantiated because of the lack of privilege.

Comment: Just for your edification there is a javascript version of Mimikatz out there if that was what you were referring to. Cheers

Comment: Ah, didn't know that about JS Mimikats. 

JavaScript loaded in a web browser has two main limits. The first is that it can't interact with the underlying operating system, only with data that the browser provides it. This blocks any low-level action like driver loading.

The second limit is the same origin policy, which only allows the script to request data from the website that originated the script. This gets a little complicated because of how "data" is defined and some intentional exceptions that websites can allow.

Comment: @shoguneye: What is the JavaScript Mimikatz you refer to? Any links?

Comment: Sure, this is a link that was contained within this link

Comment: Ooops sorry                                                                    https://adsecurity.org/?page_id=1821                                                <script src="https://gist.github.com/subTee/7e3f8979eafbe65d63e2.js"></script>